# How to create an image of a running EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am running a side-project on EC2 with an Ubuntu image because I need to do some computing intensive things there.

Now I don't need to do them each and every day right now (mostly because I do most development on weekends) and I would like to find a way how to prevent to pay EC2 24/7.

I understand that shutting down an instance requires that everything you did on that image is gone so my question is: Is there any way that I could create an image before I shut down an instance (to prevent costs) and then load that image, start a new instance and continue where I left off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There sure is:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/dg/2006-06-26/bundling-an-ami.html

That said, you probably won't want to do this after each and every session.  You should do this once after installing and configuring your software, and mount an [elastic block device](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) to store your data.

Comment: the link is a 404

Answer (score 0):

As luke pointed out, creating an AMI at the end of every session will work, but it looks like a high time demand task to do so often. I will probably tackle the me situation creating a script to install the applications that I use and using EBS to store the important information.

To exemplify it:

I will create a script that will do the following:

```
 #/sbin/bash -e
 yum -y update
 yum -y install httpd
 yum -y install php
 yum -y install mysql 
 svn checkout [url] /var/www/html/yourrepodestination
 service httpd start
```

Then I will make sure that I store the data that you need, on an EBS volume and make sure that the script will connect the ebs to my dev environment.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need me to make something more clear.

thanks,

Geo

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the image to change.  Make your image capable of loading a dataset from elsewhere (your hard drive, a remote server, or maybe S3, for instance) on startup, and then resuming.  Then make it save the dataset there when it shuts down.